# Control click event on a iframe Inno Setup (inno-web-browser)

Tags: inno-setup

I found this "add-on" called "inno-web-browser" made by the user of the forum here TLama, very good this addon, could open a url perfectly, but I need to know if you have as I monitor the clicks and therefore pursue installation or something, for example:

The URL will be something http://www.example.com/ads.php

This file "ads.php" will generate an advertisement: This advertisement will be time that will be a common banner (single image) and it will take time it will be done in flash, so far so good.

I wonder if it has the lock button while the NEXT page iframe (ads.php) is being charged, and the NEXT button is released only after the user clicks on the ad (image or flash).

You can do this?

Comment: There is currently no event of that web browser control published (since I've made this library just for fun). But to your problem, you want to be notified immediately after the user clicks on an advert, what is from the web browser control's point of view navigation to a certain URL, right ? If that is so, then there's a few events available for being notified about navigation. You can be notified before you navigate to that advert target, after it's loaded etc. Which one would be the best suitable for you ? Would you like to enable the Next button after the advert target is loaded, or when ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the most suitable for me is that: the Next button be enabled after the user clicks on the iframe (ad). You know if have how to do this really? And how can I do?

Comment: It'd need to modify the library and make a new build of it. So, if you'll be patient, I'll try to make this in few days.

Comment: Sure, wait yes friend, surely will also help others, thank you very much.

I even tried to compile the "MainUnit.pas" but I could not compile on any compiler, I tried with the Free Pascal Compiler, Dev-Pascal, Lazarus, always gives error on the "uses/dependencies/units" ....

"uses
   Classes, Windows, OleCtrls, SHDocVw;
"

I hope you do soon, I'll be waiting and thank you again, is to be congratulated :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added an event handler for the [`BeforeNavigate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event of the web browser control. The example script is now extended by this new feature. So first get [`the most recent version`](https://code.google.com/p/inno-web-browser/source/browse/#svn/trunk) and use a code like follows. It disables Next button on the custom page with the browser, unless the user clicks the Users tab of the shown StackOverflow site. But be very careful with this disabling since not all the users can be connected to the Internet, and those will get stucked with your installer:

```
[Setup]
AppName=Web Browser Project
AppVersion=1.0
DefaultDirName={pf}\Web Browser Project

[Files]
Source:"WebBrowser.dll"; Flags: dontcopy

[Code]
const
  EVENT_BEFORE_NAVIGATE = 1;

var
  CustomPage: TWizardPage;

type
  TWebBrowserEventProc = procedure(EventCode: Integer; URL: WideString);

procedure CreateWebBrowser(ParentWnd: HWND; Left, Top, Width, Height: Integer; 
  CallbackProc: TWebBrowserEventProc);
  external 'CreateWebBrowser@files:webbrowser.dll stdcall';
procedure DestroyWebBrowser;
  external 'DestroyWebBrowser@files:webbrowser.dll stdcall';
procedure ShowWebBrowser(Visible: Boolean);
  external 'ShowWebBrowser@files:webbrowser.dll stdcall';
procedure NavigateWebBrowser(URL: WideString);
  external 'NavigateWebBrowser@files:webbrowser.dll stdcall';

procedure OnWebBrowserEvent(EventCode: Integer; URL: WideString); 
begin
  // this event will fire with the EVENT_BEFORE_NAVIGATE event code whenever
  // you browse somewhere; this includes all iFrames and redirections, so for
  // your case will be the best wait until your user navigate to the target of
  // the ad (in this example unless user clicks the Users tab on StackOverflow)
  if (EventCode = EVENT_BEFORE_NAVIGATE) and (URL = 'http://stackoverflow.com/users') then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CustomPage := CreateCustomPage(wpWelcome, 'Web Browser Page', 
    'This page contains web browser');
  CreateWebBrowser(WizardForm.InnerPage.Handle, 0, WizardForm.Bevel1.Top, 
    WizardForm.InnerPage.ClientWidth, WizardForm.InnerPage.ClientHeight - WizardForm.Bevel1.Top,
    @OnWebBrowserEvent);
  // I've been getting JSON error; so please ignore it, it's not my fault
  NavigateWebBrowser('http://stackoverflow.com/');
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup;
begin
  DestroyWebBrowser;
end;

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin  
  ShowWebBrowser(CurPageID = CustomPage.ID);
  if CurPageID = CustomPage.ID then
    WizardForm.NextButton.Enabled := False;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you friend, the update was great, congratulations, I tested the code is working perfectly, but in this case was defined a URL that is loaded in the same frame, then came a doubt. When ads open in a new window (new tab), the browser is open (internet explorer), is how to detect and monitor this too?

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry, the best I can suggest is, modify that ad to not open the new window. It would get more complicated than I was planning to be. Like I mentioned, Inno Web Browser was made for fun, not as a serious project and sorry, I'm busy now to maintain it anyhow. It is built in Delphi, so if you're familiar with this language, you may contribute ;-) But, easier might be if you'd have Delphi 2009 and build your own InnoSetup with `TWebBrowser` control.

Comment: Anyway thanks, helped me a lot friend, unfortunately only understand and even PHP, know very little of Delphi, including the latest version installed and I'm learning a bit, I managed to fit a function to the onclick event in TWebBrowser OnStateChange but click only works on the page does not work on a link and / or picture, so now I went the other way, I'll get a function and put on a timer, so that it is checking if the iexplore.exe process is running. if is open (after the click), the button is enabled again, your code helped me a lot, I'll try to adapt it to my use, in the latter case.

Comment: Do directly in Delphi. Another thing, maybe you can help me, I could not compile this file MainUnit.pas the WebBrowser.dll (tried the Free Pascal Compiler, Dev-Pascal, Lazarus), now I'm with the RAD Studio here but do not know how to do, I can explain this, I believe it is quite simple. And thank you once again, is to be congratulated, I noticed that you are very good at Delphi :D

Comment: You're welcome! I'm not sure if this will work in Lazarus at least because Lazarus is multiplatform whilst the `SHDocVw` is tied just to the Windows Internet Explorer. In Delphi you can try to open the *.dpr file (Delphi Project File). And, you might [`consider to accept the answer`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541) :-)

Comment: I'm programming directly in Delphi, the "OnNewWindow2" is what I need, I tested with it, works perfectly the way I need :)

From what you told me, as I have TWebBrowser integrate directly into Inno Setup, I try to learn to do this and compile my own Inno with TWebBrowser, so I can use the codes directly.